# Counting of clicks in divs

Tags: javascript

I tried to make the script for counting the clicked links in 3 different div's. Can you please add some notes whats wrong with my code.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
span = document.getElementById('span');
var sumcount = 0;
span.innerHTML = sumcount; // Записываем начальное значение

    document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    var countItem1 = 0,
        countItem2 = 0,
        countItem3 = 0;

    if (target.className == 'item1') {
        countItem1++;
        sumcount++;
        //здесь отсылаем новые данные на сервер, при удачном ответе обновляем содержимое span
        span.innerHTML = countItem1;
    }

    if (target.className == 'item2') {
        countItem2++;
        sumcount++;
        //здесь отсылаем новые данные на сервер, при удачном ответе обновляем содержимое span
        span.innerHTML = countItem2;
    }

    if (target.className == 'item3') {
        countItem3++;
        sumcount++;
        //здесь отсылаем новые данные на сервер, при удачном ответе обновляем содержимое span
        span.innerHTML = countItem3;
    }
}
}
```

I do not understand this part of code, can you please explain it for me. merci

```
    document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
```

Comment: The part you said you don't understand is cross browser compat code. The || returns the first defined (truthy) alternative. It allows writing code for the case when the exact same thing has different property names depending on the browser.

Comment: When posting a question, you should always include a description of what your code is doing incorrect, or what errors it's producing, or something else for clarification.

Comment: Complementary to Matthew's comment: It's a short form of `if( e.target ) { target = e.target; } else { target = e.srcElemet; }`

Answer (score 0):

Those counters should be declared *outside* the handler function just like "sumcount".

The code at the beginning of the event handler copes with Internet Explorer, which doesn't pass the event reference as a parameter and which calls the event target property "srcElement" instead of "target".

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Kit did a fine job explaining it:

> The Event model is implemented differently in IE and Firefox. In IE, there is an explicit window.event object that logs any details of an event (ie: onclick) when it occurs, while in Firefox and other W3c compliant browsers, an inexplicit Event object is automatically passed into the function associated with the event handler that contains similar info about the event.[1](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/event.shtml)